# APEX Trigger Round decimal place to a specific number

Tags: apex, trigger, decimal

I am working on a trigger that sets the price of that a customer pays us. There are requirements that I am struggling with meeting.

If the decimal for the price is lower than .95 then it needs to be rounded up or set to .95, eg $1.50 would be rounded to 1.95.

If the decimal for the price is greater than .95 then it needs to be rounded up to the next 1.95, eg $1.96 would be rounded up to 2.95.

Comment: The Apex [Decimal](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_decimal.htm) class has all the methods you need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Who needs an if statement:

- 1.94 + .05 = 1.99 round up to 2.0 - .05 = 1.95
- 1.95 + .05 = 2.0 Round up to 2.0 - .05 = 1.95 - I ran a test to prove this one out
- 1.96 + .05 = 2.01 round up to 3.0 - .05 = 2.95
- 3.35 + .05 = 3.4 round up to 4.0 - .05 = 3.95

In other words:

```
//Assume your price variable is called price
price += .05;
price = price.round(System.RoundingMode.UP);
price += -.05;
```

### Boredom Update

A gentleman I know pointed out a while ago that you achieve the "normal" rounding behavior in a pretty simple way:

```
Decimal value += .5
Integer roundedValue = (Integer) value;
```

I just adopted that methodology to fit your case. The differences are

1. you always want to round up
2. your "half-way" point is .95 as opposed to .5.

Answer (score 2):

That is not a rounding mode supported by the [`Decimal`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_decimal.htm) class, but it's easy enough to implement in logic.

What you need to do is *truncate* the value (chop off the fractional amount) and then subtract the result from the value so you get back just the fraction. Then you can easily write logic comparing the fraction to 0.95.

The way to get this fractional value, assuming your dollar value is a `Decimal` value (as it should be), is to call

```
myFraction = myDecimal.round(System.RoundingMode.DOWN))
```

You can implement your logic from there to make adjustments to the final price.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a static method you can use to do your custom rounding.

```
static Decimal roundAmount(Decimal originalAmount, Decimal roundTo){
  Decimal cents = (originalAmount - Math.Floor(originalAmount));
  Decimal dollars = (originalAmount - cents);
  if ( cents > roundTo ){
     dollars++;
  }
  return (dollars+roundTo);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have created a static method that will work in your scenario

```
 public static decimal RoundOf(Decimal value){
    long ceilingValue = value.round(System.RoundingMode.CEILING);
    //Calculate mod value because Math.Mod is not supporting decimal
    decimal divideValue = value / 1;
    decimal c= Math.floor(divideValue);
    decimal modValue = value - (1 * c);
    //end

    if(modValue <= .95){
        return ceilingValue - .05;
    }else{
        return ceilingValue + .95;
    }
}
```

Example:

```
RoundOf(.93) // output = .95
RoundOf(.96) // output = 1.95
RoundOf(1.92) // output = 1.95
RoundOf(1.96) // output = 2.95
```